# Unable to change buffer size via settings

Tags: audiokit

I have a custom C node done with AudioKitEX.
My node always receives a buffer size of 512.
I've tried changing the settings to a different buffer size, but the buffer size always stays the same at 512. How can I change it ?

This is what I tried, and I was expecting to get a buffer size of 1024 i my node, but no, still got 512..

```
Settings.bufferLength = .veryLong
                
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredIOBufferDuration(Settings.bufferLength.duration)
```

AudioKit 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Right, so I came to the conclusion that the buffer size is not something that can be set from AudioKit, but it is dictated by the hardware. For example I was getting 512 when running my app on the iOS simulator, but 1024 when running on a real iPhone device...